# SQL Server table design - don't want two records the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the tables in my database has three columns.

They are `dt_id` (PK), `dt_name` (varchar) and `u_id` (FK).

`dt_id` is a identity column.

But I want to have so that `dt_name` can only be once per user.

So you can only put in " dt_name='CC', u_id=1 " once.

How can I set the `dt_name` column so ?

----Edit:----

Sorry, i will explain better..

dt_it is just a id on the table.
dt_name is the value field
u_id is the id on a user.

I want to be able to add dt_name unique on each user, so u_id=1 could have value 'CreditCard' only once. But u_id=2 could also have it, but only once..

Hope this clears it up a little..
I'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique index for "dt_name".

```
create unique index ix_dt_name on your_table(dt_name)
```

[edit] not exactly sure what you're asking; if you want the combination of name & id to be unique, you'd create the unique index on both of the columns:

```
create unique index ix_dt_name_and_id on your_table(dt_name, u_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UniqueNamePerUser ON tab
(
   dt_name, u_id
)
```

Comment: Note that the "NONCLUSTERED" keyword is specific to SQL Server (since he didn't mention what database he was using)

Comment: you are right. but i think tag sql-server refers to MS SQL server.

Comment: ahh, looks like that tag was added after I posted.

Comment: Since NONCLUSTERED would be the default anyway, it doesn't seem terribly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a unique index on (u_id,dt_name)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_u_id_dt_name on mytable(u_id,dt_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you only want dt_name to display 'CC' once in your database. If that is the case you would need to create a trigger in your DataBase to achieve this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
ON { table | view }
[ WITH ENCRYPTION ]
{
 { { FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }
    [ WITH APPEND ]
    [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]
    AS
    [ { IF UPDATE ( column )
        [ { AND | OR } UPDATE ( column ) ]
            [ ...n ]
    | IF ( COLUMNS_UPDATED ( ) { bitwise_operator } updated_bitmask )
            { comparison_operator } column_bitmask [ ...n ]
    } ]
    sql_statement [ ...n ]
 }
}
```

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

The link explains the use of all these. Therefor you can have a check before entering the row to see if the name exists. If it does then run the second script in the trigger.

EDIT **

The other codes are more efficient. but a trigger could still work. However I won't keep digging into it if the others are better suited. Best of luck.

Comment: I think I'd just create the index.